# Use controller donwolad a XLS file, and in the xls file contains the macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xls

I need a page for donwload the file for export the data in a xls/xlsm file, and in the file xls/xlsm, i need add the code macros. with ruby on rials, how i can do this?

VBA code include in the xlsm:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub HelloWorld()

MsgBox "Hello world !"

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the example code to export the data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to do this with work, and the tool I found the most handy is the `axlsx_rails` gem. It allowed me to, in ruby, generate and download excel files of whatever data I wished.

Here's a link: https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails

Here's a simple snippet of what it can do:

```rb
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Table") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["Build Matrix"]
    sheet.add_row ["Build", "Duration", "Finished", "Rvm"]
    sheet.add_row ["19.1", "1 min 32 sec", "about 10 hours ago", "1.8.7"]
    sheet.add_row ["19.2", "1 min 28 sec", "about 10 hours ago", "1.9.2"]
    sheet.add_row ["19.3", "1 min 35 sec", "about 10 hours ago", "1.9.3"]
    sheet.add_table "A2:D5", :name => 'Build Matrix', :style_info => { :name => "TableStyleMedium23" }
  end
```

To handle this in rails, you set up your controllers to respond to `.xlsx` and render the file when you hit the controller, as is laid out in more depht on the gem website. Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, but i want add a macros in the xls/xlsm, Axlsx-Rails juste create the xls file.

Comment: Wait, so do you want to add macros into an *existing* xlsx file? If so, then you're probably not looking to Ruby on Rails but just Ruby

Comment: i'll create a new xlsx file, and in the new file, i want add a VBA with this file. thks.